# I'm encountering an issue in VsCode when working with Docker Compose. Whenever I open a `docker-compose.yml` file, I receive the following error:

Tags: docker-compose, dockerfile

Unable to load schema from '[https://raw.githubusercontent.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/master/schema/compose-spec.json](https://stackoverflow.com)': Request vscode/content failed unexpectedly without providing any details.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWZMM.png)

- I'm using Visual Studio Code.
- My internet connection is working.

Any help or insights on how to fix this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you behind company proxy ? May be by disabling proxy on startup will work. 

code --no-proxy-server –

Comment: Or you can also use below steps 
```- access it manually directly pasting the url on browser```
```- reload IDE window```